Commutator between $P^\mu$ and $\phi$ (complex scalar field)
For a real scalar field the following expressions for $H$ and $P^\mu$ are valid (Peskin):
$:H:=\int \omega(a^\dagger a)\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega}$
$:P^\mu:=\int k^\mu(a^\dagger a)\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega}$
For the complex scalar field one can find that:
$:H:=\int \omega(a^\dagger a + b^\dagger b)\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega}$
$:P^\mu:=\int k^\mu(a^\dagger a +b^\dagger b)\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega}$
What I find non-intuitive is the fact that in both cases:
$[iP^\mu,\phi]=\partial^\mu\phi$.
While I understand that that is the case for the scalar field, how is this possible for the complex scalar field?

Have you learned about momentum as generator of translations? This applies regardless of the field involved.

@Ghoster Hi! Yes I have, similarly as to how angular momentum operator is a generator of rotations, the momentum is a generator of translation. What confuses me is the fact, that for both types of fields, the commutator is the same. But in the complex one, you have $\phi$ and $\phi^\dagger$. And the dependency from $\phi^\dagger$ doesn't appear at all

Isn’t the commutator of momentum with $\phi^\dagger$ similar? Why would you expect $\phi^\dagger$ to have anything to do with translating $\phi$?

The commutator of the momentum operator with the field gives you the result an infintesimal translation. For a scalar field $\Phi$ (let's assume it is complex although it doesn't matter), under a translation $x^\mu\rightarrow x^\mu + \epsilon^\mu$, where $\epsilon^\mu$ is small, $\Phi(x^\mu)$ transforms as (using an active\ view of transformations)
$$
\Phi(x^\mu) \rightarrow \Phi(x^\mu+\epsilon^\mu) = \Phi(x^\mu) + \epsilon^\mu \partial_\mu \Phi(x^\mu) + O(\epsilon^2)
$$
Therefore the infintesimal transformation is $\delta \Phi = \epsilon^\mu \partial_\mu \Phi $, so we would expect $[P_\mu, \Phi] = \partial_\mu \Phi$, as you found, with no complex conjugate.
One way to understand this is to decompose $\Phi$ into real and imaginary parts, $\Phi(x)=R(x) + i J(x)$, where $R$ and $J$ are real fields. Then suppose $R=0$. We wouldn't expect that a translation of the field to change its sign, but that's exactly would would happen if $\Phi^\dagger$ appeared in the commutator.
More formally, we could also decompose the commutator of the complex field $\Phi$ in the commutators of the real fields $R$ and $J$ you already understand (we'll use the property of commutators of linear operators that $[A, i B] = i [A, B]$)
$$
[P_\mu, \Phi] = [P_\mu, R] + i [P_\mu, J] = \partial_\mu R + i \partial_\mu J = \partial_\mu (R + i J) = \partial_\mu \Phi
$$
Another way to understand it is that there is a corresponding rule $[P_\mu, \Phi^\dagger] = \partial_\mu \Phi^\dagger$, so in this way there is a symmetry between $\Phi$ and $\Phi^\dagger$.
Finally, a more "physical" way to understand it is that usually when there is a complex scalar field, the action has a $U(1)$ symmetry that guarantees conservation of charge. In the formula $[P_\mu, \Phi] = \Phi^\dagger$, the left hand side would have charge $1$ while the right hand side would have charge $-1$, so would violate the $U(1)$ symmetry (aka conservation of charge).

Quite an insightful answer!
One question only, why do we associated U(1) with charge?

@imbAF (a) "Charge" is a general name that refers to the conserved quantity that arises in Noether's theorem, especially for internal symmetries. (b) The symmetry in electromagnetism that generates conservation of electric charge is a $U(1)$ symmetry, which you can find by applying Noether's theorem. More reading: wikipedia, or this one, Sections 1.3 and 6.3 of Tong's QFT notes, any QFT book.

A complex field has essentially two independent types of components (e.g. "holomorphic" and "antiholomorphic" modes, or alternatively real and imaginary modes), and these components commute with each other: $a$-type operators commute with $b$-type operators.  Hence, the action of $P^\mu$ (as defined by you) on the complex field decomposes into the action of $P^\mu$ two independent scalar fields (one defined with $a$-type operators and the other with $b$-type operators.)  If you accept that $[iP^\mu, \phi] = \partial^\mu\phi$ for one real scalar field, then it is also true for two independent real scalar fields.  Assuming $\psi = \phi_r + i\phi_c$, you might write
\begin{align*}
\phi_r(x) = \int\frac{d^3k}{2\omega_k}(a_k + a_{-k}^\dagger)e^{ik_\mu x^\mu},\\
\phi_c(x) = \int\frac{d^3k}{2\omega_k}(b_k +b_{-k}^\dagger)e^{ik_\mu x^\mu}
\end{align*}
where the $a$ and $b$ operators each satisfy commutation relations of the form $[a_k, a^\dagger_{k'}] = 2\omega_k\delta^3(k-k') = [b_k, b^\dagger_{k'}]$.
Had you defined the $a$ and $b$ operators differently, the commutator of $P^\mu$ (given by $\int \frac{dk}{2\omega_k}k^\mu(a_k^\dagger a_k + b_k^\dagger b_k)$) with $\psi = \phi_r + i\phi_c$ might look weirder, but the weirdness would be an artifact, either of how the "momentum" was constructed or of how the wave vector is interpreted for each component, or of choosing a different sign convention for the Fourier transform for the real and imaginary parts.  Even in such contrived cases, you could still find an operator that generated translations in real space, i.e. a momentum operator as conventionally understood.
